# React Native Expo Issue With Starting Project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a React Native app. I am able to run it using the xcode simulator. When I try to open the app on my phone it doesn't work. Expo has the text "No App Configuration Data" that is greyed out by a mask. Has anyone ever experienced this? If so, how did you go about solving the issue?

In the console I see these 2 errors that might be causing the problem:

> %c action %cFETCH_APP_CONFIG_ERROR %c@ 19:11:33.064 color: gray; font-weight: lighter; color: inherit; color: gray; font-weight: lighter;

and

> %c action     color: #03A9F4; font-weight: bold {"type":"FETCH_APP_CONFIG_ERROR"}

Here is my code where the error is being thrown:

```
import { FETCH_APP_CONFIG, FETCH_APP_CONFIG_ERROR, FETCH_APP_CONFIG_SUCCESS, UPDATE_APP_CONFIG } from '../actions/appConfig';
const initialState = {
  config: {},
  error: {},
  loader: false
};
const basicAppConfig = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
      case FETCH_APP_CONFIG:
        return { ...state, loader: true };
      case FETCH_APP_CONFIG_ERROR:
        return { ...state, loader: false, error: action.payload };
      case UPDATE_APP_CONFIG:
        return { ...state, loader: false, config: action.payload };
      case FETCH_APP_CONFIG_SUCCESS:
        return { ...state, loader: false };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default basicAppConfig;
```

Comment: Have you solved this? I'm experiencing the same error than you.